# Obtaining all repeated characters' position in a string using Java Stream API

Tags: java, functional-programming

Input is a string, and the method should return repeated characters in that string and the position of these characters.

I'm currently using Java 8 Stream. The problem is I have to do it by calling 2 times collectors. I am trying to find a way to combine all these operations in 1 single collector operations if possible.

Furthermore, the operation of mapping of characters and their position in a string is still performed in another method since I have not found a way to perform that.

Please give suggestion of improvement for the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "acbdaghfb";

    Map<Character,List<Integer>> map=charMaps(str);
    map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"_"+v));
}

public static Map<Character,List<Integer>> charMaps(String str) {

    Map<Character, List<Integer>> maps = encodeString(str)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    maps = maps.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

    return maps;
}

public static List<Pair<Character, Integer>> encodeString(String str) {
    List<Pair<Character, Integer>> pairs = new LinkedList<Pair<Character, Integer>>();
    char chars[] = str.toCharArray();

    for (int a = 0; a < chars.length; a++) {
        pairs.add(new Pair<Character, Integer>(chars[a], a));
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `encodeString` and you do not even need a `Pair` class. You only use this method to build a list of each index with the character of the string at that index. Instead, you can directly use an `IntStream` that will go over the indexes of each character of the String.

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> map =
    IntStream.range(0, str.length())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str::charAt, HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

This creates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) going from 0 to the length of the String (excluded). We turn this primitive Stream into a `Stream<Integer>` using [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--): we will need to box each index to store them in a list anyway, and having a `Stream` of objects enable us to use the built-in [`groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector.

This collector groups each element of the Stream by the classifier given. In this case, the classifier is a function returning the character at the index considered. It is using the [method-reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `str::charAt` (which would be equivalent to the lambda expression `i -> str.charAt(i)`). The downstream collector is used to collect all elements that are classified to the same key; in this case, it is simply [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) which will collect the indexes into a list. By default, `groupingBy` isn't specified to return a specific `Map` implementation (the current Oracle JDK returns a `HashMap` but that cannot be relied upon). Since we're going to post-process that map, giving `HashMap::new` as the map supplier makes sure that we end up with a `HashMap`.

The Stream API [doesn't offer a way to do a `GROUP BY HAVING`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818307/java-8-streams-api-having-clause-equivalent-in-a-groupingby), like we would like here (in SQL jargon), so 2 passes are needed. The second one can be simplified though: instead of creating a new Stream pipeline, we can use

```
map.values().removeIf(l -> l.size() <= 1);
```

to remove every entry from the map where the value is a list that has a size less than 1. This works because [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) returns a view of the map, so changes to it reflect through the map. And then [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) gives us the ability to remove the elements matching the given predicate.

So all in all, you can have:

```
public static Map<Character,List<Integer>> charMaps(String str) {
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> map =
        IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str::charAt, HashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
    map.values().removeIf(l -> l.size() <= 1);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Since the `List` values will definitely contain at least one element (for unique characters), I'll suggest making the `removeIf()` predicate `l -> l.size() == 1`. +1 anyways. :)